# Restoring minifig parts to original configuration for sale

Tags: minifigures

I have approx 100 Lego Figures (besides extra 'body parts') but I know that most are not as originally issued.  While all are Lego parts they are all mixed up.  I'd like to sell the whole lot, but concerned that I have to restore them to their original (uniform)look - or at least in their original look they would command a (somewhat) higher price. Any recommendations or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [minifigs section of Brickset](http://brickset.com/minifigs) to help you. They have reference of over 9000 minifigs released by TLC over time. By browsing per topic, you may complete some of your minifigs and using the site is completely free.

There are also several books like this [Complete Lego Minifigure Catalogue (1975-2015)](http://www.minifigure.org/), even if books may offer a higher challenge to search. Moreover, books are not free.

Answer (score 0):

A book with all figures has been published in 2014 by Dotling Kindersley Ltd, 80 Strand London

Comment: Welcome to LEGO Answers! Could you expand this answer to explain how to find this book (perhaps link to it somewhere) and how it would be helpful for restoring minifigs to their original configuration?